# Answer not following width format

Tags: support, bug, design

The link in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486541/asp-net-mvc-rc-creating-a-mvc-user-control-with-a-codebehind/486583#486583) answer runs outside of the fixed width, using IE7.

Comment: In **Opera** the URL breaks across two lines, not replicating on that browser.

Comment: @random: Same for FireFox.

Comment: I can replicate in Chrome 3.0.195.27

Comment: Replicated on Chrome 4.0 too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in browsers, not our code. Easy fix: use smaller URLs! That one is pathologically big.

Comment: I dont remember that answer being like that before, even though it has been a long time

Comment: since this answer was done back in January im pretty sure someone if not me would have reported the issue earlier if it was always like that

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we replicate here using a super duper long URL which unlike in comment, will not get truncated.

Let me try:
http://blog.lozanotek.com/archive/2008/10/20/Visual_Studio_Templates_for_MVC_Views_without_Codebehind_Files.aspx

Does it overlap to the right-bar in Chrome and IE7/8?

Screenshot of this post (v1) in Chrome 3.0.195:
[image: Overlapping (Chrome)]

Comment: Oh yes it does!

Comment: Still looks fine in **Opera.**